# How to send a simple HTML file from a bash script with the curl command using SendGrid's SMTP API?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am new to bash scripting. I have spent hours searching for a solution..

```
#!/bin/bash

# EMAIL_TO, FROM_EMAIL, etc variables are initialized here
# ...
# ...

maildata='{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "'${EMAIL_TO}'"}]}],"from": {"email": "'${FROM_EMAIL}'",
    "name": "'${FROM_NAME}'"},"subject": "'${SUBJECT}'","content": [{"type": "text/html", "value": "'${bodyHTML}'"}]}'

curl    --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
        --header 'Authorization: Bearer '$SENDGRID_API_KEY \
        --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        --data "'$maildata'"
```

---

The snippet above works fine whenever bodyHTML is set here, inside the script. 
But I want an external html *file* to be sent in this manner.

So, the question:
How can I send, for example, "mail.html" using the above scheme?
(How to set the bodyHTML variable? What command(s) to use? 
*bodyHTML=$(cat "mail.html")* # results in an error message on executing the curl line)

The issue seems to have to do with the bodyHTML (initialized either from file or within script) containing double quotation marks. As in , for example. But what to do with it...? Perhaps I need to first serialize HTML as JSON within the script..? How?

Comment: did you try `bodyHTML="$(cat mail.html)" ; echo "$bodyHTML"` ? (Side issue: You can save a process creation by using `bodyHTML="$(< mail.html)"` instead). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem.
I still don't know exactly what value to give in "value":..... part.
(If I leave it as is, curl still gives the error message, 
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]})

Comment: try --data-urlencode instead of --data

Answer (score -1):

i guess bodyHTML needs proper json-encoding, try

```
maildata='{"personalizations": [{"to": [{"email": "'${EMAIL_TO}'"}]}],"from": {"email": "'${FROM_EMAIL}'",
"name": "'${FROM_NAME}'"},"subject": "'${SUBJECT}'","content": [{"type": "text/html", "value": '$(printf "%s" "${bodyHTML}" | php -r 'echo json_encode(stream_get_contents(STDIN));')'}]}'
```

... ofc they should probably ALL be properly json-encoded, not just the HTML, but the html seems like the thing *most* likely to break your json here..